# How to write SQL to pull latest not null data from multiple rows using group by function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write SQL for MS SQL to pull  the latest records of each column for each `number`

This is how data looks like:

[image]

This is how I want my output:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Also, will it make any better if i change my INSERT statement and include the TYPE Column, Can I take the latest record of each TYPE and run any aggregate function (MIN/MAX) ? :

[image]

Comment: Your design change will make it better, because then you'll `row_number` your rows with `partition by type`, select only 1'st records and then apply `max` to have a single value per number.

Comment: @astentx, Can you please give me an example ? I don't understand how can i take only 1st record ? Do i need to do any sorting before that ?

Comment: No one but you knows what your "table" (i use that term loosely) represents nor what each row of your output represents. Does each row represent a city? a assignment? Your sample data is very small and any suggestions will make assumptions based on that sample. What happens when there are multiple rows for London? For Smith? For a different date? What does Number signify in your table? Does your output contain the Last Name - and, if so, how do you know which Name value to include?

Comment: @ShivamAgrawal Updated mu answer for this case. Assuming you do not have nulls as real values in corresponding columns for entity of the `Type` type.

Comment: But in any case of table structure it is bad idea to store completely different types of entities in single catchall table and make decoding of values in select statement. Better to use different tables for different entity types and one routing table with relation between them with corresponding checks and referential integrity.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty tricky.  One method is to use correlated subqueries or lateral joins:

```
select *
from (select distinct number from t) n outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.city
      from t t2
      where t2.number = n.number and t2.city is not null
      order by t2.record_date desc
     ) c outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.region
      from t t2
      where t2.number = n.number and t2.region is not null
      order by t2.record_date desc
     ) r outer apply
     . . .
```

Unfortunately, you have to do this one column at a time.

The SQL standard has a construct `IGNORE NULLS`, which can be used with `LAG()` to support exactly what you want to do.

Another method, by the way, is conditional aggregation"

```
select number,
       max(case when seqnum_city = 1 then city end) as city,
       max(case when seqnum_region = 1 then region end) as region,
       . . .
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by number
                                order by (case when city is not null then 1 else 2 end), record_date desc
                               ) as seqnum_c,
             row_number() over (partition by number
                                order by (case when region is not null then 1 else 2 end), record_date desc
                               ) as seqnum_r,
             . . .
      from t
     ) t
group by number;
```

I am not sure which of these alternatives would have better performance.

Comment: Do you suggest any small change in the design 'How data is being inserted here' to make the SELECT easy ?

Comment: @ShivamAgrawal . . . The simplest solution is to repeat all values in the table rather than using `NULL` to say the value did not change.  This also has the advantage of supporting `NULL` as a valid value in any of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot your columns to rows, calculate first values and then pivot back. Unpivot ignores nulls for you. But first you need to convert all to varchar not to have type conflicts.
[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=407ff7a8f2d2bc7d4263db4a9dbe2610)

```
with a as (
  select
    1 as num,
    cast(null as varchar(100)) as city,
    cast(null as varchar(100)) as region,
    cast('John' as varchar(100)) as name,
    cast(null as varchar(100)) as assigned,
    cast(null as varchar(100)) as reportsto,
    '2020-11-10 05:12' as recorddt
  union all
  select 1, null, null, 'Smith', null, null, '2020-11-10 05:13' union all
  select 1, 'London', 'EU', null, null, null, '2020-11-10 05:15' union all
  select 1, null, null, null, 'Team A', '425', '2020-11-10 05:17' union all
  select 1, null, null, null, 'Team X', '234', '2020-11-10 05:18'
)
, unp as (
  select
    num,
    col,
    val,
    row_number() over(partition by num, col order by recorddt desc) as rn
  from a
  unpivot(
    val for col in (City, Region, Name, Assigned, ReportsTo)
  ) q
)
select
  num,
  [city],
  [region],
  [name],
  [assigned],
  [reportsto]
from (
  select *
  from unp
  where rn = 1
) a
pivot(
  max(val) for col in ([city], [region], [name], [assigned],[reportsto])
) p


| num | city   | region | name  | assigned | reportsto |
+-----+--------+--------+-------+----------+-----------+
| 1   | London | EU     | Smith | Team X   | 234       |
```

**UPD**:
Code and [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=1dc4dc9db96297b113e021d53581dc87) for updated model.

```
with a as (
  select
    1 as num,
    cast(null as varchar(100)) as city,
    cast(null as varchar(100)) as region,
    cast('John' as varchar(100)) as name,
    cast(null as varchar(100)) as assigned,
    cast(null as varchar(100)) as reportsto,
    'Person' as type_,
    '2020-11-10 05:12' as recorddt
  union all
  select 1, null, null, 'Smith', null, null, 'Person', '2020-11-10 05:13' union all
  select 1, 'London', 'EU', null, null, null, 'Location', '2020-11-10 05:15' union all
  select 1, null, null, null, 'Team A', '425', 'Assignment', '2020-11-10 05:17' union all
  select 1, null, null, null, 'Team X', '234', 'Assignment', '2020-11-10 05:18' union all
  select 2, 'LA', 'US', null, null, null, 'Location', '2020-11-10 05:22'
)
, row_num as (
  select
    a.*,
    row_number() over(partition by num, type_ order by recorddt desc) as rn
  from a
)
select
  num,
  max(city) as city,
  max(region) as region,
  max(name) as name,
  max(assigned) as assigned,
  max(reportsto) as reportsto
from row_num
where rn = 1
group by num
```

Comment: . . Although a clever approach, this requires that all columns be the same type.